# jQuery - Add Hamburger Mobile Menu Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a Hamburger type icon to my Menu bar, while in mobile version. The icon is added using the code ☰ - and#9776;

I am trying to add it in Java code so that when the Menu is opened the icon should disappear and when the menu is closed the icon should reappear next to the menu name

Is it possible using just the code ☰ ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".menu-Trigger").click(function() {

        jQuery(".nav-menu").slideToggle(10, function() { 
             jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-Expanded").css("display", "");  
            if($(".nav-menu").is(":hidden")) {
                $(".menu-Trigger").text("Menu");
            } else {
                $(".menu-Trigger").text("Close");
            }

          });

    });
});
```

HTML and CSS Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Arshdeep Soni</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">

            body {
                background-image: url(Final6Lower.jpg);
                background-size: auto 100%;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;

            }

            .nav-menu li, .nav-menu a{
                display: inline-flex;
                color: rgb(137, 134, 134);
                text-decoration: none;
                font-family: Raleway;
                padding-right: 15px;
                font-size: 12px;
                letter-spacing: 7px;

            }
            .nav-menu {
                margin-top: 25px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .nav-menu li, .nav-menu a:hover {
                color:white;
            }

            .socialIcons img {
                height: 50px;
                width: 50px;
                opacity: 0.4;
                filter: alpha(opacity=40);
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
            icons img {
                position:relative;
                display: inline;
                margin-right: 0 auto;
                margin-left: 0 auto;
            }

            .icons {
                text-align: center;
                position:absolute;
                bottom:10px;
                left:0;
                width: 100%;

            }

            .socialIcons img:hover {
                opacity:1;
                color:white;
            }

            .menu-Trigger {
                display:none;
            }

            div.nav-menu ul {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }

            div.nav-menu ul li {
                list-style: none;
            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

                .menu-Trigger {
                    display: block;
                    color:white;
                    background-color: black;
                    padding:13px;
                    text-align: center;
                    cursor:pointer;
                    font-family: raleway;
                }

                div.nav-menu ul li {
                    position: relative;
                    display:block;
                    float:none;
                    padding:13px;
                    background-color: black;
                    height: auto;
                }

                div.nav-menu {
                    display:none;
                }

                div.nav-Expanded {
                    display: block;
                }
            }


        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="header">
        </div>                    
        <span class="menu-Trigger" align="center" >&#9776; Menu</span>
        <div class="nav-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href=#>HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>VIDEOS</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>IMAGES</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

            <div class="icons">
                <a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.youtube.com" title="Subscribe on YouTube" alt="Arshdeep on YouTube"><img src="youtube.png"/></a>
        <a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.instagram.com/ArshSoni" title="Subscribe!" alt="Arshdeep Soni"><img src="instagram.png" /></a>
<a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.facebook.com/MagicArsh" title="Arshdeep Soni on Facebook" alt="Facebook"><img src="fb.png" /></a>
                <a class="socialIcons" href="http://twitter.com/ArshSoni" title="Follow Arshdeep on Twitter" alt="Twitter"><img src="twitter.png" /></a>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the code snippet supposed to help us with something?

Comment: I added the code to show my existing jQuery code - and I wanted help to add the icon

Comment: Are you adding Java or JavaScript code? Those are very different things. Also, can we see your html code you're binding to?

Comment: I for one would need more to go with, like the html structure, and the CSS, to even know how and where anything is placed, so I could begin to think about an answer.
I think the answer is "yes, there is a way", but I couldn't tell you more at this point.

Comment: I have added the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) you're using jquery, which is a javascript library. Completely different than Java.

Yes, you can use the symbol in your jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".menu-Trigger").click(function() {

        jQuery(".nav-menu").slideToggle(10, function() {
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-Expanded");
            if($(".nav-menu").is(":hidden")) $(".menu-Trigger").text("☰"); else $(".menu-Trigger").text("Close");
        });
    });
});
```

I had no idea what the `.css('display', '')` was doing, so I removed it. What ever you think you're doing it is doing on every click of the button, which does make sense in a slide-out panel that does something different to open it and something else to close it.

**Also:** Usability studies show that the hamburger, three-bar icon isn't the best choice for a navigation. It is confusing. Perhaps change it to menu like you had it.

Comment: Can I just ask how you managed to get the symbol working in the 5th line? did you simply enter the unicode or did you do anything else?

Comment: I just copied the symbol ( ctrl / cmd + c ) and pasted it ( ctrl / cmd + v ) between the quotes

Comment: It is a unicode symbol so it can go anywhere where the charset is set to accept that symbol.

Comment: Oh right I understand! I didn't know that can also work! Thanks

Comment: @RandomMath thank you. one last piece of advice, look into icon fonts. In case the unicode symbol is not supported. A font loaded with font-face will show the symbol as long as font is loaded correctly.

Comment: Oh, also the .css('display', '') is used so that when the menu button is clicked and then closed, and you enlarge the site, the menu bar disappears and displays the regular links in inline